# Run time error '1004' A table cannot over lap another table

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

Im using the below code for creating a table named as **Dashboard** and it was working fine till yesterday

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes).Name = "Dashboard"

Range("Dashboard[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Dashboard").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9 2"
```

However, now i'm getting **Run time error '1004' A table cannot over lap another table** error. Can anyone help me why i'm getting this error and how to resolve it

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably doesn't lay in your macro but in the way you/Excel handles tables. My guess would be that there previously was a table (or still is, but not visible) and with your macro you try to overwrite to that other table's range. Check under Formula's > Names if there are any (obsolete) tables covering the same range.

Another problem could be that you try to create 2 tables on the same page, where one already exists (since you hard coded the name of the table to be created).

If none of that helps, try debugging with the following code;

```
dim vTmp as variant
for each vTmp in application.ListObjects
    debug.print vTmp.name, vTmp.range
next vTmp
```

Then check for tables covering the same range.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it may not actually be a Table that is in the way and preventing the creation of the new table.... it can be instead just a named range, even a single named cell.  So the error message is a bit misleading.